# How to input a byte array in an Edittext Dialog in Android

Tags: android, arrays, dialog, android-edittext

For the last days I have been trying to implement a Edittext Dialog which the user introduces an 8-bit array (1 or 0) and then the application will transform this bit array into decimal and hexadecimal value (if it is 11111111 it will be dec=255 and hex=0xFF) but I don't know hot to implement this case. If it is not possible to implement in this way, it will be also posssible to instead of a bit input, it can be a int/decimal input.

Here is the code I have implemented to show the Edittext Dialog:

```
else if (uuid.equals(BleDefinedUUIDs.Characteristic.PASSWORD)){
                    final EditText passtext = new EditText(v.getContext());
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext())
                    .setTitle("Password Modification")
                    .setMessage("Please, introduce the new 8-bit password (with 1 or 0):")
                    .setView(passtext)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            // Code to obtain the the bit array/int from the edittext box
                        }

                    })
                    .show();
                }
```

Does anyone know how to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how you could possibly implement this functionality. I've used your code and modified it slightly.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.text.method.DigitsKeyListener;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final EditText passtext = new EditText(this);

        // Set the length to 8 characters
        passtext.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(8) });

        // Set the keypad to numeric
        passtext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

        // Only allow the user to enter 0 and 1 numbers
        passtext.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("01"));

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Password Modification").setMessage("Please, introduce the new 8-bit password (with 1 or 0):").setView(passtext).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                String binaryDigits = passtext.getText().toString().trim();

                if (binaryDigits != null && !binaryDigits.isEmpty()) {

                    // Convert the entered digits to decimal
                    int decimalValue = Integer.parseInt(binaryDigits, 2);

                    // Convert the entered digits to hex
                    String hex = Integer.toHexString(decimalValue);

                    Log.d(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "Decimal: " + decimalValue);
                    Log.d(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "Hex: " + hex);
                }
            }

        }).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!!! It works perfectly to introduce and save the value. I have another request. I would like to do the same but now I want to introduce a number with at least two decimals. It will be like introducing a time between 0.1s to 10s. You know how to this? Thanks again for the help